# How to seperate elements of string by space Java Script

Tags: javascript, string, separator

I am trying to add spaces at specific indexes of my string. For example `"21+2-32*2"` into `"21 + 2 - 32 * 2"`, but it can't be `"2 1 + 2 - 3 2 * 2`. I know that what I need to do is add spaces before and after math signs, but I don't know how to realize it in Java Script.

Thank you in advance

Comment: perhaps `str.replaceAll(/([-+/*])/g, ' $1 ')`?

Comment: @Nick Just curious what does ` $1 `  mean?

Comment: @SAM, take first group, the one with `()` in regexp.

Comment: @SAM `$1` refers to the value captured in the first set of parentheses in the regex, in this case `([-+/*])` so it will be the arithmetic operator. So basically we are matching one of `-+/*` and replacing it with itself surrounded by spaces

Comment: Thanks, @Nick and Nina. Got it 